# Finding $\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)} \frac{(x^5−y^7)}{(x^4+y^4)}.$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y)=\frac{(x^5 - y^7)}{(x^4+y^4)}$$ I have find its limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0).$ The answer is $0.$

I tried transforming it to polar coordinates, I got rid of the denominator but the numerator is tricky and  I don't know how to proceed from there.

I also thought about using the squeeze theorem, but then again I can't find what value it should be greater and less than be.

edit: 
Polar coordinates: let $x = r\cos(a), \;y = r\sin(a)$.

After simplifying the function I get

$r^5\cos^5(a) - r^2\sin^7(a)$

Comment: Can you show what you tried?  Polar coordinates are a good start.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Please know that we are all to avoid using `$\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)} f(x, y)$` in titles, for spacing reasons (trying to keep some consistency in the vertical height of titles), just as we are to avoid using `\displaystyle` or `\dfrac`, etc. in titles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$|x^5| \leq |x| (x^4 + y^4)$$
$$|y^7| \leq |y^3| (x^4 + y^4)$$
$$ \left| \frac{x^5 - y^7}{x^4 + y^4} \right| \leq |x| + |y^3|  $$

Comment: (+1) Quite cute!

Answer (score 4):

With polar coordinates you obtain
$$\frac{x^5-y^7}{x^4+y^4}=\frac{r^5(\cos^5\theta-r^2\sin^7\theta)-}{(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2}=\frac{r^5(\cos^5\theta-r^2\sin^7\theta)}{r^4-2r^4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}=\frac{r(\cos^5\theta-r^2\sin^7\theta)}{1-\frac12\sin^22\theta}$$
Now, if $r\le 1$, the numerator is  bounded from above by $2r$, and the denominator is bounded from below by $\frac12$, so that
$$0\le\Biggl|\frac{x^5-y^7}{x^4+y^4}\Biggr|\le 4r.$$

Comment: I couldn't understand why the numerator is bounded by 2r instead of r?

Comment: @MichaelBurr:  Some (freudian?) slip – I was thinking of excluding the origin because of the denominator. Fixed. Thanks for pointing this inconsistency!

Comment: @kronos: Because we don't know whether $\cos^5\theta-r^2\sin^7\theta$ is bounded by $1$, even if $r$ is. Bounding each term by $1$ is safe (it's probably not the *least* upper bound).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think polar coordinates is all that useful here. Just note

$$|f(x,y)| \le |x|\frac{x^4}{x^4+y^4} + |y|^3\frac{y^4}{x^4+y^4} \le |x|+|y|^3.$$

As $(x,y)\to (0,0),$ both $|x|$ and $|y|^3$ go to zero, hence so does their sum. By the squeeze theorem, the desired limit is $0.$